# PHP verificar si el usuario tiene una columna igual a = 1

Tags: php, mysql

estoy intentando que si el usuario tenga una columna, con un valor igual a 1 le dé el ícono de verificado, de lo contrario, si el usuario tiene la columna igual a 0 no se lo entregue, pero estoy teniendo un error en el cual no se entrega el ícono de verificado, teniendo el valor en 1.

Este es mí código:

```
$conn = new mysqli($localhost,$dbusername,$dbpassword,$dbname);
$ingresarSim = $post['uid'];
$result = mysqli_prepare($conn, "SELECT verificado FROM mybb_users WHERE uid = ?");
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($result, "i", $ingresarSim);
$final = mysqli_stmt_execute($result);

$row = mysqli_fetch_row($final);
if ($row['verificado'] == 1) {
echo '<img src="verified.gif" style="margin-left:5px;position: relative;height: 15px;margin-top: 0px;top: 2px;">';
}
```

Comment: ¿Y si `verificado` es nulo o `2`?

Comment: @Sal No entendí tu pregunta.

Comment: Ya que no has compartido la estructura de la tabla cabe preguntar  ¿la columna `verificado` puede contener valor nulo?.

Comment: @Sal No, la columna 'verificado' es un INT

Comment: Haz un `echo` de $row después del mysql_fetch_row y muéstranos que te devuelve. Por otra parte, un `uid` suele ser una cadena de caracteres, si es así en tu caso, la consulta puede estar mal hecha, porque ese parámetro debería estar entre '.

Comment: @Jakala Cuando realizo el echo luego del $row no aparece nada, solo un caracter en blanco, y hablando lo del `uid` es como A_I, es como un `ID`

Comment: Entonces es muy posible que te esté dando un error la consulta o la conexión. Haz un `print_r($final)` y dinos que tipo de objeto te devuelve

Comment: @Jakala Me aparece un número 1

Comment: Buen día, puedes hacer print_r($row) justo antes del if y decirnos que te devuelve? En el comentario anterior mensionas que está en blanco, pero no viene absolutamente nada? Eso querría decir que fetch no de $final no está funcionando correctamente

Comment: @HeytalePazguato Intenté ingresar el print_r pero no me aparece nada. ¿Está correcto como lo ingrese como me dijo? ```print_r($row);
if ($row['verificado'] == 1) {```

Comment: @HeytalePazguato Es como si no estuviese nada en la variable ¿o algo por el estilo?

Comment: Si no devuelve nada entonces el error viene de más arriba en tu código, intenta con print_r($result)

Comment: @HeytalePazguato ```mysqli_stmt Object ( [affected_rows] => -1 [insert_id] => 0 [num_rows] => 0 [param_count] => 1 [field_count] => 1 [errno] => 0 [error] => [error_list] => Array ( ) [sqlstate] => 00000 [id] => 1 )```

Comment: Aparece esto cuando ejecuté lo que usted me dijo, ¿Es antes del if verdad?

Comment: Ya vi que error tienes, estas haciendo mysqli_fetch_row en $final, cambia por $result e intenta otra vez print_r($row)

Comment: ```$row = mysqli_fetch_row($result);
print_r($row);
if ($row['verificado'] == 1) {``` este es el código que ingresé y ahora mismo no recibo nada por parte del `print_r` ¿Que devo hacer?

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/133005/discussion-between-heytalepazguato-and-user264129).

Comment: Ingresa al chat que cree para ver el problema

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cuando usas sentencias preparadas en `mysqli` debes usar [`bind_result()`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/mysqli-stmt.bind-result.php) para vincular cada resultado a una variable (debes declarar una variable para cada columna del `SELECT` en la instrucción SQL).

Considera también **no mezclar estilos**, lo cual se considera una mala práctica. Si optaste por el estilo orientado a objetos en la conexión (usando `new mysqli()`), sigue usando ese estilo en todo. Además, es más claro y más moderno.

Por ejemplo:

```
$conn = new mysqli($localhost,$dbusername,$dbpassword,$dbname);
$ingresarSim = $post['uid'];
$result = $conn->prepare("SELECT verificado FROM mybb_users WHERE uid = ?");
/* 
   vincular variables a la sentencia preparada 
   Aquí el valor de la columna del SELECT se vincula
   a una variable llamada $verificado
   que usarás luego en el if, luego del execute y del fetch
*/
$result->bind_result($verificado);
$result->bind_param("i", $ingresarSim);
$result->execute();
$result->fetch();
if ($verificado == 1) {
    echo '<img src="verified.gif" style="margin-left:5px;position: relative;height: 15px;margin-top: 0px;top: 2px;">';
}
```